# Image of Kudla-Millson pairing

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, siegel-modular-forms

Let $G=O(p,q)$ and $M$ the locally symmetric space obtained by taking th symmetric space of $O(p,q)$ and quotienting by an arithmetic group $\Gamma$. In [INTERSECTION NUMBERS OF CYCLES ON LOCALLY SYMMETRIC SPACES](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1990__71__121_0.pdf) Kudla-Millson construct a bilinear pairing
$$(-,-):H^i_c(M,\mathbb{C})\times H^{\text{dim}(M)-i}_{ct}(G,\mathcal{S}(V^n))^{\mathfrak{q}}_{\chi_m}\to \left(\text{Siegel modular forms of weight } \frac{p+q}{2}\right).$$

If we replace $G=U(p,q)$, then we instead Hermetian modular forms of weight $m$. My question is if we have some idea of what the image of this pairing is? The reason I ask is that I've read/heard people refer to the "Kudla-Millson lift" as a map from Siegel modular forms to $H^i_c(M)$ and that for sufficently large weight the lift is surjective ([for example in these notes, at the begining of section 5)](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Enicolas.bergeron/Travaux_files/Bismut.pdf). Lift (at least naively) sounds to me like the bilinear pairing $(,)$ might surjective (allowing us to give a section "the lift") but I've not seen this actually being claimed anywhere, which is why I ask.